# Error adding a WinUI 3 class library reference to a WinUI 3 blank app

Tags: dll, winui-3, class-library

First I create a blank Visual Studio Solution, then a add a WinUI3 class library(dll) project and then i add a WinUI3 blank app project.
In this stage both the project compile without errors
Now I go to the blank app and add a project reference to the class library(dll), but now the blank app does not compile and give error (sorry, translate from portuguese)
"Error NETSDK1022 Duplicate 'Page' items were added. The .NET SDK includes 'Page' items from the project directory by default. You can remove these items from the project file or set the 'EnableDefaultPageItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in the project file. For more information, check out https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were: 'MainWindow.xaml' XXXXX C:\Users\XXXXX.nuget\packages\microsoft.projectreunion.winui\0.8.12\buildTransitive\Microsoft.WinUI.targets 54"

I already try to add "EnableDefaultCompileItems" as false but does not work. I expected this to work like any WPF or Windows Form example

Comment: `EnableDefaultCompileItems` is not the same as `EnableDefaultPageItems`. Did you read the words in the error message?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake,  I try both and no one works...now I trying "EnableDefaultPageItems" and the error changes...they say now "WMC1012 A project cannot have more than one ApplicationXaml item"

Comment: Might be some conflicts with outdated Project Reunion packages. Since you won't need Project Reunion packages, you should try removing them. Check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/remove-windows-app-sdk-versions).

Comment: Thanks to all, specially @AndrewKeepCoding, the Project Reunion was the key...the class library template that I used points to ProjectReunion and the blank app to Microsoft Windows SDK.
I make both point to Windows SDK and works like a charm

Comment: Great. I posted it as an answer. Please accept it so we can close this session.

Answer (score 0):

**Project Reunion** is the previous code name for the Windows App SDK and is outdated. To solve this, you need to [remove ProjectReunion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/remove-windows-app-sdk-versions) packages.